# JavaScript dialog pop up event wait for OK to be pressed

Tags: javascript, jsf, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I got a delete (input submit) button which pops up a dialog (Alloy UI dialog, html) when clicked:

```
A.all("#RFB input.ConfirmDelete").each(function(node){
    node.on('click', function(event) {      

        if(confirmed) {
            showUserWaitDialog();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            deactivateKeyboardNav();
            deleteConfirm(node, confirmDeleteMessage, function () { //Runs the function rendering the pop up
                confirmed = true;
                event.target.click();
                showUserWaitDialog();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the `event` is running async and thus performs the deletion, and not waiting for the user to click OK (calling the callback).

The deleteConfirm takes the following arguments

```
function deleteConfirm(link, pText, callback) {
```

The content in the pop up consists of:

```
var bodyContent = '<div class="vl-info vl-message"><h2>'+titleText+'</h2>'+
                        '<p>'+pText+'</p>' +
                        '<p class="more button-area"><a href="#" class="deleteOK">'+confirmButtonText+'</a><a href="#" class="deleteNotOK">'+discardButtonText+'</a></p></div>';
```

And the button functions:

```
A.one('.deleteOK').on('click', function(e){
                            (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) && callback.apply();
                            confirmDialog.close();
                            confirmDialogOpen = false;
                        });

                        A.one('.deleteNotOK').on('click', function(e){
                            confirmDialog.close();
                            confirmDialogOpen = false;
                            return false;
                        });
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Alloy UI provides a nice Dialog box API. It may be worth to see this example and apply for your requirement.

```
var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                title : '<your dialog box title here>',
                centered: true,
                modal: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 250,
                bodyContent: <You can keep the message to display here>,
                buttons: [
                          {
                              label: 'Delete',
                              id: 'deleteBtn',
                              handler: function() {
                                 //Place code to delete here. It get executed when user click on Delete button.
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              label: 'Cancel',
                              id: 'cancelActionItemBtn',
                              handler: function() {
                                  this.close();
                              }
                          }
                          ]
            }).render();
```